# Sum Dictionary value by Key

Tags: c#, linq, dictionary

I have an XML document i am parsing using XDocument:

```
XDocument _document = XDocument.Parse(XMLString);
```

The XML i'm reading in (real example could contain many of same ItemNumber):

```
<Line>
 <ITEMNMBR>18-4695</ITEMNMBR>
 <UNITCOST>2.00000</UNITCOST>
 <UNITPRCE>7.00000</UNITPRCE>
 <QUANTITY>15.00000</QUANTITY>
</Line>
<Line>
 <ITEMNMBR>18-4695</ITEMNMBR>
 <UNITCOST>3.00000</UNITCOST>
 <UNITPRCE>7.00000</UNITPRCE>
 <QUANTITY>22.00000</QUANTITY>
</Line>
```

I then read this xml into a Dictionary :

```
var lines = _document.Descendants("Line")
                  .Select(l => l.Elements().ToDictionary(e => e.Name.LocalName, e => e.Value)).ToList();
```

Next, Get a list of distinct ItemNumbers:

```
 var itemNumbers = lines.Where(dict => dict.ContainsKey("ITEMNMBR"))
                    .Select(dict => dict["ITEMNMBR"])
                    .Distinct()
                    .ToList();
```

Now that i have a list of distinct ItemNumbers, i need to get totals for each, so i loop the Dictionary:

```
foreach (string itemNumber in itemNumbers)
  {...
```

Inside the loop is where i query for the values by ItemNumber:

```
var qty = lines.Where(dict => dict.ContainsValue(itemNumber))
                    .Select(dict => dict["QUANTITY"])
                    .ToList();
```

The next area is where i'm having an issue. Can i calculate the sum for qty? I tried something like this, but get compiler errors (which is understandable, i'm trying to sum a string)

```
int sum = qty.Sum(x => Convert.ToDecimal(x.Value));
```

I get "String does not contain a definition for Value"...

How can i sum these results?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use the `Value` field, you already selected the value in the following line

```
var qty = lines.Where(dict => dict.ContainsValue(itemNumber))
          .Select(dict => dict["QUANTITY"]) // here you are selecting the value
          .ToList();
```

so you are not working with a `KeyValuePair` anymore but with the value. Simply sum the conversion

```
int sum = qty.Sum(x => Convert.ToDecimal(x));
```

You can `Select` to decimal with a more resilient conversion function if you want to make sure that the string is a decimal

Comment: Although i like Chris Hardie's approach more, i like that you pointed out the obvious that i somehow overlooked...

Comment: Thanks, I upvoted his answer for the optimization. Although sometimes Linq one-liner can become a bit complicated in this case it is really easily applicable without being tricky.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a more terse version where we perform the sum in the first query:

```
 var sum = lines.Where(dict => dict.ContainsValue(itemNumber))
                .Sum(dict => Convert.ToDecimal(dict["QUANTITY"]));
```

Comment: One minor change (.Sum(dict => Convert.ToDecimal(dict["QUANTITY"]))), but works great!  Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I would try something like this:

```
decimal sum = qty.Sum(x => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(x) ? Convert.ToDecimal(x) : 0);
```

I am checking if `x` is not null or empty for edge cases, in which the `Convert.ToDecimal` would fail.